# TomEE and legacy Entity Beans

Tags: jboss, javabeans, apache-tomee, openejb, tomee-7

I'm trying to migrate a legacy web application currently running on a deprecated environment based on JBoss (older than 2001).

The project seems to use entity beans since trying to deploy its jars on Wildfly 10.0.1 returns an error about not deployable entity beans (because they are not supported anymore).

I switched to TomEE 7.0.1 where my entity beans gets recognized but something suddenly triggers a chain of errors.

```
00:13:57.174 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.init ------------------------- localhost -> /sample
00:13:57.247 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureApplication Configuring enterprise application: /root/apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1/webapps/sample
00:13:57.451 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.InitEjbDeployments.deploy Auto-deploying ejb ConsorziSession: EjbDeployment(deployment-id=ConsorziSession)
00:13:57.452 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.InitEjbDeployments.deploy Auto-deploying ejb Consorzi: EjbDeployment(deployment-id=Consorzi)
00:13:57.452 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.InitEjbDeployments.deploy Auto-deploying ejb Coninfo: EjbDeployment(deployment-id=Coninfo)
00:13:57.452 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.InitEjbDeployments.deploy Auto-deploying ejb Infallegati: EjbDeployment(deployment-id=Infallegati)
00:13:57.465 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureService Configuring Service(id=sample/OracleDS, type=Resource, provider-id=Default JDBC Database)
00:13:57.466 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createRecipe Creating Resource(id=sample/OracleDS)
00:14:10.577 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.unusedProperty unusedProperty maxTotal - sample/OracleDS
00:14:10.577 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.unusedProperty unusedProperty maxWaitMillis - sample/OracleDS
00:14:10.580 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureService Configuring Service(id=Default Stateless Container, type=Container, provider-id=Default Stateless Container)
00:14:10.581 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.createContainer Auto-creating a container for bean ConsorziSession: Container(type=STATELESS, id=Default Stateless Container)
00:14:10.581 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createRecipe Creating Container(id=Default Stateless Container)
00:14:10.603 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.processResourceRef Auto-linking resource-ref 'openejb/Resource/sample/OracleDS' in bean ConsorziSession to Resource(id=sample/OracleDS)
00:14:10.605 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.processResourceRef Auto-linking resource-ref 'openejb/Resource/OracleDS' in bean ConsorziSession to Resource(id=sample/OracleDS)
00:14:10.607 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureService Configuring Service(id=Default CMP Container, type=Container, provider-id=Default CMP Container)
00:14:10.607 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.createContainer Auto-creating a container for bean Consorzi: Container(type=CMP_ENTITY, id=Default CMP Container)
00:14:10.607 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createRecipe Creating Container(id=Default CMP Container)
00:14:10.621 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.processResourceRef Auto-linking resource-ref 'openejb/Resource/sample/OracleDS' in bean Consorzi to Resource(id=sample/OracleDS)
00:14:10.622 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.processResourceRef Auto-linking resource-ref 'openejb/Resource/OracleDS' in bean Consorzi to Resource(id=sample/OracleDS)
00:14:10.622 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.processResourceRef Auto-linking resource-ref 'openejb/Resource/sample/OracleDS' in bean Coninfo to Resource(id=sample/OracleDS)
00:14:10.623 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.processResourceRef Auto-linking resource-ref 'openejb/Resource/OracleDS' in bean Coninfo to Resource(id=sample/OracleDS)
00:14:10.623 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.processResourceRef Auto-linking resource-ref 'openejb/Resource/sample/OracleDS' in bean Infallegati to Resource(id=sample/OracleDS)
00:14:10.624 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.processResourceRef Auto-linking resource-ref 'openejb/Resource/OracleDS' in bean Infallegati to Resource(id=sample/OracleDS)
00:14:10.625 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureService Configuring Service(id=Default Managed Container, type=Container, provider-id=Default Managed Container)
00:14:10.625 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.createContainer Auto-creating a container for bean sample.Comp1731051780: Container(type=MANAGED, id=Default Managed Container)
00:14:10.625 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createRecipe Creating Container(id=Default Managed Container)
00:14:10.637 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.core.managed.SimplePassivater.init Using directory /root/apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1/temp for stateful session passivation
00:14:10.651 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.processResourceRef Auto-linking resource-ref 'openejb/Resource/sample/OracleDS' in bean sample.Comp1731051780 to Resource(id=sample/OracleDS)
00:14:10.651 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.processResourceRef Auto-linking resource-ref 'openejb/Resource/OracleDS' in bean sample.Comp1731051780 to Resource(id=sample/OracleDS)
00:14:10.652 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.deploy Configuring PersistenceUnit(name=cmp)
00:14:10.656 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.logAutoCreateResource Auto-creating a Resource with id 'sample/OracleDSJta' of type 'DataSource for 'cmp'.
00:14:10.656 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.deploy Configuring Service(id=sample/OracleDSJta, type=Resource, provider-id=sample/OracleDS)
00:14:10.657 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createRecipe Creating Resource(id=sample/OracleDSJta)
00:14:23.834 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.unusedProperty unusedProperty maxTotal - sample/OracleDSJta
00:14:23.834 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.unusedProperty unusedProperty maxWaitMillis - sample/OracleDSJta
00:14:23.835 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.setJtaDataSource Adjusting PersistenceUnit cmp <jta-data-source> to Resource ID 'sample/OracleDSJta' from 'null'
00:14:23.835 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.setNonJtaDataSource Adjusting PersistenceUnit cmp <non-jta-data-source> to Resource ID 'sample/OracleDS' from 'null'
00:14:24.286 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.ReportValidationResults.logResults WARN ... Consorzi:    Unused ejbPostCreate method: ejbPostCreate()
00:14:24.287 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.ReportValidationResults.logResults WARN ... Coninfo: Unused ejbPostCreate method: ejbPostCreate()
00:14:24.287 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.ReportValidationResults.logResults WARN ... Infallegati: Unused ejbPostCreate method: ejbPostCreate()
00:14:24.287 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.ReportValidationResults.logResults 3 warnings for EjbModule(path=sample)
00:14:24.288 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.AppInfoBuilder.build Enterprise application "/root/apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1/webapps/sample" loaded.
00:14:24.288 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication Assembling app: /root/apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1/webapps/sample
00:14:24.579 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.createDelegate PersistenceUnit(name=cmp, provider=org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider) - provider time 250ms
00:14:24.579 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.destroyApplication Undeploying app: /root/apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1/webapps/sample
00:14:24.581 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke ContainerBase.removeChild: destroy: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: An invalid Lifecycle transition was attempted ([before_destroy]) for component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/sample]] in state [STARTING_PREP]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.invalidTransition(LifecycleBase.java:408)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:296)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:828)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeploy(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1586)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeploy(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1566)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeployWebApps(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:754)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.destroyApplication(Assembler.java:2224)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:1035)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:717)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1257)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1115)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5076)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:702)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1107)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1841)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

00:14:24.585 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.doResourceDestruction Closing DataSource: sample/OracleDS
00:14:25.112 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal Unable to deploy collapsed ear in war StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/sample]
 org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Creating application failed: /root/apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1/webapps/sample: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.3.v20160428-59c81c5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [cmp] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /root/apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1/sample (File o directory non esistente): javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.3.v20160428-59c81c5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [cmp] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /root/apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1/sample (File o directory non esistente)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:1039)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:717)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1257)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1115)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5076)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:702)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1107)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1841)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.3.v20160428-59c81c5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [cmp] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /root/apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1/sample (File o directory non esistente): javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.3.v20160428-59c81c5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [cmp] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /root/apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1/sample (File o directory non esistente)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:870)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.3.v20160428-59c81c5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [cmp] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /root/apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1/sample (File o directory non esistente)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.createDelegate(ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.java:121)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.<init>(ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.java:105)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.PersistenceBuilder.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceBuilder.java:155)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:864)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.3.v20160428-59c81c5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [cmp] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /root/apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1/sample (File o directory non esistente)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.createPredeployFailedPersistenceException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:2035)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:2026)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:313)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.EntityManagerFactoryCallable.call(EntityManagerFactoryCallable.java:64)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.createDelegate(ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.java:119)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.3.v20160428-59c81c5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [cmp] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /root/apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1/sample (File o directory non esistente)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.predeployFailed(EntityManagerSetupException.java:231)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /root/apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1/sample (File o directory non esistente)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProcessor.loadStandardMappingFiles(MetadataProcessor.java:484)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProcessor.loadMappingFiles(MetadataProcessor.java:393)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.processORMetadata(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1948)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /root/apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1/sample (File o directory non esistente)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:215)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:145)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:154)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.ArchiveFactoryImpl.createArchive(ArchiveFactoryImpl.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.ArchiveFactoryImpl.createArchive(ArchiveFactoryImpl.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProcessor.loadStandardMappingFiles(MetadataProcessor.java:469)
    ... 27 more

00:14:25.113 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/sample]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:702)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1107)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1841)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEERuntimeException: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Creating application failed: /root/apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1/webapps/sample: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.3.v20160428-59c81c5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [cmp] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /root/apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1/sample (File o directory non esistente): javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.3.v20160428-59c81c5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [cmp] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /root/apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1/sample (File o directory non esistente)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1269)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1115)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5076)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Creating application failed: /root/apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1/webapps/sample: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.3.v20160428-59c81c5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [cmp] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /root/apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1/sample (File o directory non esistente): javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.3.v20160428-59c81c5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [cmp] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /root/apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1/sample (File o directory non esistente)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:1039)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:717)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1257)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.3.v20160428-59c81c5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [cmp] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /root/apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1/sample (File o directory non esistente): javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.3.v20160428-59c81c5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [cmp] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /root/apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1/sample (File o directory non esistente)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:870)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.3.v20160428-59c81c5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [cmp] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /root/apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1/sample (File o directory non esistente)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.createDelegate(ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.java:121)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.<init>(ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.java:105)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.PersistenceBuilder.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceBuilder.java:155)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:864)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.3.v20160428-59c81c5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [cmp] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /root/apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1/sample (File o directory non esistente)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.createPredeployFailedPersistenceException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:2035)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:2026)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:313)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.EntityManagerFactoryCallable.call(EntityManagerFactoryCallable.java:64)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.createDelegate(ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.java:119)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.3.v20160428-59c81c5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [cmp] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /root/apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1/sample (File o directory non esistente)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.predeployFailed(EntityManagerSetupException.java:231)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /root/apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1/sample (File o directory non esistente)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProcessor.loadStandardMappingFiles(MetadataProcessor.java:484)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProcessor.loadMappingFiles(MetadataProcessor.java:393)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.processORMetadata(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1948)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /root/apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1/sample (File o directory non esistente)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:215)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:145)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:154)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.ArchiveFactoryImpl.createArchive(ArchiveFactoryImpl.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.ArchiveFactoryImpl.createArchive(ArchiveFactoryImpl.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProcessor.loadStandardMappingFiles(MetadataProcessor.java:469)
    ... 27 more

00:14:25.113 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Error deploying web application directory /root/apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1/webapps/sample
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/sample]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:730)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:702)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1107)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1841)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I really can not understand why it is not running as the errors seem quite messy.

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I'm in a similar situation migrating from Glassfish 4.1.1 to TomEE 7.0.5.

Answer (score 0):

Few things to validate before going furthers:

- does it work with default tomee distribution (ie using openjpa)
- does it work referencing the context (webapp) with an absolute path in server.xml instead of using auto deployments on Host?